# Sequelize: findAndCountAll(), but with a specific row as the first entry

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

I've a table that I'm querying using `findAndCountAll()`

I'm basically using it for pagination/ordering using the `order`, `limit` and `index` properties. Something simple like this:

```
exports.getApplications = async(req, res, next) => {
    const findOne = req.query.indexId;
    const index = req.query.index || 0;
    const limit = req.query.limit || 10;
    const orderField = req.query.orderField || 'createdAt';
    const orderDirection = req.query.orderDirection || 'DESC';
    const order = [ orderField, orderDirection ];

    const applications = await Application.findAndCountAll({   
        order: [order],      
        limit: parseInt(limit, 10), 
        offset: parseInt(index)
     
        // ...
    }
}
```

But I'd also like to be able to specify a particular `indexId` (`findOne`), and have that single entry appear before the paginated/ordered list (***edit**: *The row may or may not be included in the paginated list that's returned*)

Is that possible using `findAndCountAll`? Or would I have to run a separate query using `findByPk()`, reduce the limit by 1, then unshift the entry to the front of the results array?

Thanks,

Nick

---

*Edit - Implementation in case anyone is interested. Now just have to make the queries run in parallel :)

```
try {
    // Find a specific row to highlight if needed
    if(findOne) {
        topRow = await Application.findByPk(findOne, {
            include: [...],
        });
    }

    const applications = await Application.findAndCountAll({
        include: [...],
        order: [order],      
        limit: parseInt(limit, 10), 
        offset: parseInt(index)
    });

    // If there's a row to be highlighted
    if(topRow) {
        const visible = applications.rows.filter(application => application.id === topRow.id);
        const index = applications.rows.findIndex(application => application.id === topRow.id);

        // 1 too many results in the array
        if(applications.rows.length + 1 > limit) {
            // If the row appears in the array to be returned, remove it
            if(visible) {
                applications.rows.splice(index, 1);
            } else {
                // Remove the last element instead
                applications.rows.pop();
            }
        } else { 
            if(visible) applications.rows.splice(index, 1);
        }
        
        // Add the highlighted topRow to the array
        applications.rows.unshift(topRow) 
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to do this, assuming your `findOne` value is safe to use:

```
order: [
  [sequelize.literal(`id = ${findOne}`), 'DESC'],
  [orderField, orderDirection]
]
```

This will return `true` for the row you want, `false` for others, so it will first sort it to the top, then continue the rest of the ordering.

Comment: Nice, I had no idea you could order it like that! One thing though - wouldn't this rely on the `findOne` value being present within the paginated results? I'm trying to get a row that's potentially outside of the results the `ofset`/`limit` options return

Comment: You can also put `CASE` statements into `ORDER` if you want to do some custom logic! I can see `offset` being a problem here, may have no choice but to do 2 queries.
Depending on how much data you have, and its not pretty... you could do `findAll()` and do the offset/limit on the returned array. Better practice would be to run 2 queries, with parallel promises, then concat the unique results. An identity lookup is fast.

Comment: Nice one, thanks - It ended up being a pretty interesting in terms of if the row was visible or not in the original results. It seems to be working pretty well, now just need to make the two queries run in parallel - which I guess is just a case of not awaiting the individual queries, and awaiting them in Promise.all()